# Http status code for Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot

i have a SpringBoot controller, and i want to return the correct http code status for Exceptions. So, my question is: Which http statu code is better for Exception the "500" one or "409" one?

This is my code:

```
@PostMapping(value = {"", "/"})
public ResponseEntity<Response> create(@RequestBody StudioDto studioDto,
        ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse) {

    Response response = new Response();

    try {
        studioService.createStudio(studioDto);
        response.setMessage("The studio was create");
        response.setStatusCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.setMessage("Op we have a little problem");
        response.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());

        //Which one
        //this one 5xx
        response.setStatusCode(500);
        //Or this one 4xx
        response.setStatusCode(409);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity(response, response.getHttpStatus());
}
```

Comment: One rough guideline I use is the following: Think about retries. If there’s a chance that a retry with the same request will be successful, it’s a 5xx (example: connectivity issue to database which was resolved a few seconds later). If a retry with the same request will always result in this error, it’s a 4xx (example: invalid field in the request). This way, a client knows whether it makes sense to retry or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the recommended way to handle exceptions, you should use controller advice , check this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

The status code is defined by the specific scenario , 500 means internal server error which I would use for a problem which it's cause is not specified, for 409 it resembels conflict on the target resource

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current
>   state of the target resource. This code is used in situations where
>   the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the
>   request

you have many other status code which is suitable in different cases so I would say no specific status code is the right answer, you can check this [link](https://httpstatuses.com) for more info

Answer (score 11):

Todd gave a great link.  This is a better way of thinking about it:

> https://httpstatuses.com/
>
> - 1×× Informational
> - 2×× Success
> - 3×× Redirection
> - 4×× Client Error   *    400 Bad Request   * 401 Unauthorized
>   ...   * 405 Method Not Allowed
>   ...
> - 5×× Server Error   * 500 Internal Server Error   * 501 Not Implemented   * 502 Bad Gateway ...

In other words, each major number (200, 400, 500, etc.) is a *CATEGORY*.  You can "refine" the error code by choosing a specific error within the "category".

To your original question:

- If the *Client request* is "bad" (for example, illegal username/password), then return a 4xx.
- If the *Server* somehow fails (for example, you can't read the database), then return a 5xx.

The "official" list of HTTP error codes is RFC 7231:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what message you are trying to convey. Think of the status code as guidance to the caller on what to do next. If it's an internal server error that the user is unlikely to be able to do anything about, [a 500](https://httpstatuses.com/500) error is appropriate.

> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

On the other hand, [a 409](https://httpstatuses.com/409) indicates a conflict that the user could conceptually resolve:

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource. This code is used in situations where the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.

Most 400-level errors indicate that the user could, in theory, fix them and resubmit.

Personally, I would advise you to catch more exact exceptions and determine which status code each should return, because it really depends on your use case. As of now, you are catching `Exception`, and that could be just about anything so it's hard to tell what kind of guidance you should give the caller.

Answer (score 1):

5.XX codes mean error from the server side and 4.XXX codes mean error from the client side.
Here you catch any exception :

```
 catch (Exception e) {
    response.setMessage("Op we have a little problem");
    response.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());

    //Which one
    //this one 5xx
    response.setStatusCode(500);
    //Or this one 4xx
    response.setStatusCode(409);
}
```

So **it is clearly impossible** to know if the problem came from the client request (bad parameter for example) or from a server error (inconsistency in DB or programmatic error for example).

To be able to set with precision 4.XXX or 5.XXX, your code could rely on some specific base exceptions as `ClientErrorException` and  `ServerErrorException`.

Throw one or the other according to the error cause and you could then rely on them to set the correct status code :

```
try {
    studioService.createStudio(studioDto);
    response.setMessage("The studio was create");
    response.setStatusCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
} 
 catch (ClientErrorException e) {
    response.setStatusCode(409);
}
catch (ServerErrorException e) {
    response.setStatusCode(500);
}
```

Another way could be to add the status code field in the exception base class.
You could so simply write :

```
try {
    studioService.createStudio(studioDto);
    response.setMessage("The studio was create");
    response.setStatusCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);

} 
 catch (MyRestException e) {
    response.setStatusCode(e.getStatusCode());
}
```

These custom exceptions could be thrown directly from your code as you detect an  error in the client request (`4.XXX`).
In this way, you could consider all other exceptions as related to server processing (`5.XXX`).
A Spring Exception Handler could easily perform this task.