# Whats the correct HTTP status code answer for specific Exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a REST Web API in C# using ASP.NET Web API for MVC 5.

I've created an abstract class `BaseApiController`, which all API controllers extend. In this base controller I handle all the Exceptions and everything the controllers need to properly work.

I've already implemented exception handling for the following Exceptions:

```
    public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string controllerName = null;
        string actionName = null;

        try
        {
            SetContext(controllerContext);
            SetServices();

            await AuthenticateUser();

            controllerName = controllerContext?.Controller?.GetType().FullName;
            var services = controllerContext?.ControllerDescriptor?.Configuration?.Services;
            actionName = services?.GetActionSelector()?.SelectAction(controllerContext)?.ActionName;

            return await base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException e)
        {
            ClientDataService.Logger(e, $"{controllerName}.{actionName}",
                $"Response -> Status Code: {(int)e.Response.StatusCode}, Reason: {e.Response.ReasonPhrase}",
                SystemLogOriginTypesEnum.WEBSITE_API);

            throw;
        }            
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ClientDataService.Logger(e, $"{controllerName}.{actionName}",
                $"Response -> Status Code: {(int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError}, Reason: Internal server error",
                SystemLogOriginTypesEnum.WEBSITE_API);

            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Internal server error"),
                ReasonPhrase = "Internal server error"
            });
        }
```

The Controllers throw `HttpResponseException` mainly when mandatory parameters aren't passed or properly setup (HTTP status code
 400), the second is when something went terribly wrong (HTTP status code 500).

My question is what kind of HTTP status code should the API respond when a service throws exceptions like a `NotSupportedException` or a custom `InvalidSortAttributeException`?

I don't mean HTTP status categories, i.e., 4XX vs 5XX, since the `InvalidSortAttributeException` should be a 4XX category because the error gets thrown from an invalid request, maybe a 400 (Bad Request)!?

Although the second, I believe could fall on both categories since the server doesn't support the request but it doesn't exactly mean it will not support it in the future, maybe a 406 (NotAcceptable) or a 501 (NotImplemented)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Http status code for Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139728/http-status-code-for-exceptions)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate, because on the linked post only the HTTP error categories are discussed. Mainly when to use 4XX vs 5XX. I already accepted the 4XX category should be used at least for the InvalidSortAttributeException since it is an error thrown when the user sends a wrong Sort attribute, perhaps the NotSupportedException could be a 5XX. Still, I'm more focused on what specific errors should be used or are most commonly used in similar scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4XX is built specifically for user errors
The 5XX is built for internal server errors

You have to respond with an intelligent code for the scenario. If there is a notsupported exception but your code caller constructed a not supported scenario, then it's 500. If the user managed to put together a bad request, it should be 4XX.

Note also that there's a difference between missing an attribute in the JSON request (400) and missing a value in the url (404) or the resource is no longer available (404).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @c-bauer. Based on your reply I changed both to answer with a 400 (Bad Request) since both are based on the Request made by the client using the API. Which means he's requesting things that don't exist, at least yet.

Comment: Glad to be of help @PedroPinto. You can mark this as the answer if you feel that this is a good response to your question, or leave it open in the event you want more feedback.